# SQL Server: select TOP2 element by group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

I have a table with following columns:
item (varchar)
date (date)
revision (datetime)
value (numeric)

I have this SQL statement that finds the last revision for each item:

```
select item, max(revision) as 'last_revision' 
from [mytable] 
group by item 
ORDER BY last_revision ASC
```

However I am looking to get the last 2 revisions for each item:

item|last_revision|previous_revision

I have tried this which fails miserably

```
select TOP 2 item, revision as 'last_revision' 
from [myTable] 
group by item 
ORDER BY last_revision ASC
```

> Column 'myTable.revision' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this queries. Both of them should work

```
select
    item, revision
from (
    select 
        item, revision
        , rn = row_number() over (partition by item order by revision desc)
    from [mytable] 
    group by item , revision
) t
where rn <= 2
```

Or

```
select
    distinct item, revision
from (
    select 
        item, revision
        , rn = dense_rank() over (partition by item order by revision desc)
    from [mytable]
) t
where rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT item, revision AS last_revision
FROM
(
    SELECT item, revision,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY revision) rn
    FROM [myTable]
) t
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

SQL Server's `TOP` operator just limits the number of records returned for the entire result set, not for each group in your aggregation.  You really should use analytic functions here.

Comment: thank you for the info on TOP. I tried your query but it seems to return twice the same (last) revision, instead of the last and the one before

Comment: @RockScience Add sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You appears to want `top (4)` with `ties`

```
select top (4) with ties item, revision  
from mytable t
order by row_number() over (partition by item order by revision desc)
```